# Failed to create parent directory in flutter

Tags: flutter

I downloaded the flutter file in my friend's google drive, extract and then try to run the program but the program cannot run properly. Can someone help me with this problem?

[image: Failed to create parent directory in flutter]

Comment: Please put the error message as text, not as a printscreen.